# Computing Cholesky Factorisation by Hand

Tags: numerical-methods, numerical-linear-algebra

It is a common exam problem to compute the Cholesky factorisation of a small (typically 4x4) matrix. I know that this can be done by first finding the matrix $U$ in the $LU$-decomposition (e.g. by the Gauss algorithm) of the given matrix and then multiplying it from the left with the diagonal matrix $$D=\operatorname{diag}\left(U_{11}^{-1/2},\cdots,U_{nn}^{-1/2}\right).$$ The resulting matrix will be the sought after matrix in the Cholesky factorisation.

Of course, finding the $LU$-decomposition can be quite cumbersome sometimes. Since speed is of the essence in exams, my question is the following:

> What is the quickest way of computing the Cholesky factorisation of small matrices by hand?